# Three divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I've been trying now for a while to fit three divs in next to each other. But the one that's supposed to be to the right is not positioned next to the others. It kinda jumps down. As you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
#left {
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
#middle {
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
#right {
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Missing picture

Comment: Precise with picture

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `display:flex;` and specify the flex direction you want using `flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;`

Also you should attach these CSS properties to a `<div></div>` which contain all of your three divs.

You can find all information about this here: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

you can simple solved using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
#middle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;

    height: auto;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;

    float: right;
    height: auto;
}
```

I recommendation using `display:inline-block`.

If you can using `display:inline-block`, you can write clean code

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic List Group</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              <style>  *{
                    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
                    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
                    box-sizing:border-box;
                }
                .span3{
                 width:33.33%;
                 float:left
                 height:250px;
                 display:block;
                 clear:both}
         </style>

    <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="span3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,</div>
              <div class="span3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,</div>
              <div class="span3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: grid` on parent element,

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; //defines how many columns (fr means fraction, so in this case .wrapper is divided in three equal fractions)
 grid-column-gap: 10px //space between elements
}
```

More here: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Add add the following source in your css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Bootstrap **Grid** system (`latest version bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`)

Bootstrap’s `grid system` uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content. It’s built with `flexbox` and is `fully responsive`. Below is an example and an in-depth look at how the grid comes together.

learn https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
or use

Bootstrap **Flex**

Quickly manage the `layout`, `lignment`, and `sizing` of `grid columns`, `navigation`, `components`, and more with a full suite of responsive `flexbox` utilities. For more complex implementations, custom `CSS` may be necessary.

learn https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/